# How to remove a key-value pair from swift dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I want to remove a key-value pair from a dictionary like in the example.

```
var dict: Dictionary<String,String> = [:]
//Assuming dictionary is added some data.
var willRemoveKey = "SomeKey"
dict.removePair(willRemoveKey) //that's what I need
```

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can use this:

```
dict[willRemoveKey] = nil
```

or this:

```
dict.removeValueForKey(willRemoveKey)
```

The only difference is that the second one will return the removed value (or nil if it didn't exist)

### Swift 3

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: willRemoveKey)
```

Comment: this should now be called `dict.removeValue(willRemoveKey)` since it looks like .removeValueForKey has been renamed - thanks for the help!

Comment: So nice and so clean. Love it!

Comment: If your values are optionals how can the subscript syntax work?

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that the docs say this is O(n) where n is the size of the dictionary?!

Comment: @WiseOldDuck Assigning the subscript to `nil` always deletes the key. To assign a true `nil` value in a dictionary with an optional Value type, assign `.some(nil)`.

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 5**, **Swift 4**, and **Swift 3**:

`x.removeValue(forKey: "MyUndesiredKey")`

Cheers

Answer (score 13):

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: willRemoveKey)
```

Or you can use the subscript syntax:

```
dict[willRemoveKey] = nil
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var dict: [String: Any] = ["device": "iPhone", "os": "12.0", "model": "iPhone 12 Pro Max"]

if let index = dict.index(forKey: "device") {
   dict.remove(at: index)
}

print(dict) // ["os": "12.0", "model": "iPhone 12 Pro Max"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For serial removal:

```
let forbidenParameters = [
            "key1",
            "key2",
            "key3"
        ]       
let cleanParameters = parameters.filter { !forbidenParameters.contains($0.key) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let dict = ["k1": "v1" , "k2": "v2"]
  for ( k, _) in dict{
        dict.removeValue(forKey: k)
       }
```

- Just Loop through it and remove value for key
- removeValue(forKey : k) for value